# Update SettingsPane after user signs in

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm hoping that someone can help me with this. What I'm trying to do is after a user logs into  the and is authenticated, I want to update the settings pane to show Sign Out (in place of Sign In) along with other settings that I may want to be visible. I already have the SettingsFlyout pages created just need to know how to them viewable based on if they're logged in or not. Please help...thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you're using MVVM, you can just bind the Visibility to a field on the view model.

Comment: I'm not versed in MVVM so I wouldn't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

So if you're not using MVVM, I would suggest the following (somewhat hack-y in my opinion) approach. Somewhere in your code (probably where you create the page you want to be visible depending on logged in status) create a property that points to your page. Let's call this location MainPage.

```
public static FrameworkElement SettingsPage { get; set; }
```

Then when you create the page:

```
var page = new SettingsFlyout( ); // Overly simplified
SettingsPage = page;
```

Then, where you have your log-in code, do something like this:

```
public void SetLoginStatus( bool loggedIn )
{
    if(loggedIn)
    {
        MainPage.SettingsPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage.SettingsPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

That should get you where you need to be. But generally speaking, this isn't the best way to accomplish this. You should research MVVM a little, as it solves a lot of these data communication problems very simply after you overcome the initial learning curve (which isn't that steep). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks William, I will look into MVVM and go from there! Also could you set this up in the App.xaml.cs or does it have to be on a particular page?

Comment: This can't really be set up in the App.xaml, as that is primarily for loading resources and initializing the app itself. But this concept can be applied to any page. Just try and adapt it to fit your needs, see what works, and expand on it. Also, if this is your preferred solution, don't forget to upvote and mark as answer! Thanks!